# How to make the entire screen containting a (LinearLayout + ListView) scrollable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have an Android fragment in which contains a Vertical LinearLayout with two layouts inside it: Another inner Vertical LinearLayout (which takes at least half of the screen) and a ListView (which shows a number of smaller Views). A good way to think about it is something like a facebook post along with several comments showing below it.

The problem I am facing is that the the inner LinearLayout is not scrollable and therefore parts of the ListView stays outside of the screen and there is no way to scroll the screen up to see the entire ListView (the inner layout could possibly take up the entire screen). Placing the entire layout inside a ScrollView is also known to be a bad practice.

I know one solution is to make the entire layout to be a ListView with the first cell to be the inner LinearLayout, followed by the cells from the original ListView. That however has its own issues: It is harder to recycle the views in the ListView, and generally I also see it as a bad practice where one cell has a different behavior from all other cells in the ListView.

Is there a better solution to this? I can imagine this is a typical problem and I hope to find a better solution than above.

Comment: If parts of the listview are off the screen, you have a bug in your xml.  Or you should be using a relative layout instead of a linear to ensure that doesn't happen.  Also, if you actually want the top view to scroll with the list, the correct way is to make it the list header, not to make it a cell in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
ListView yourListView = new ListView(this);
yourListView.addHeader(getHeaderView());
```

You can also add footer to a ListView. When you do this, the header(or footer) will become part of the ListView, and so it will be scrollable. You can find the document here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about header and footer views. It just did not come to my mind when I was looking for a solution. This is exactly what I was looking for.